# where are my disks?

Tags: mount, live-cd

Newbie struggling. I want to use ubuntu-remix-recovery live cd to attempt to recover a crashed disk. I've got the live cd loaded and bootable, no problem. I need to run ddresuce and save the logfile. With using a live cd, I can't save anything on the cd. So I've got a usb drive plugged in. After stumbling around I found /dev/disk/by-label that shows all my disks. But the value ../../sdg1 or /dev/sdg1 isn't a directory. So how do I get to the data on the disks. Do I need to do a mount?

With the live cd, I can't save any info. In addition, a command like ls -l | more stops after 1 page of output, so there are a lot of directories that I can't even browse if there is more than 1 page.

I was pretty good at unix commands 15 years ago but that was 15 years ago. Been Windows since then. Any pointers to a quick start on Ubuntu would be helpful. Seems most of the online help I've seen requires you to ask specific question and I'm not that literate yet.

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Running a program like `gparted` will show you the disks.

Answer (score 0):

Yours disks are in the `/dev/` (short for devices) directory.

You can list them by using the command

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

which lists all the partitions (and disks) on your system. You can usually identify your device by the size or manufactor name that lists with the above command.

Each disk is given a name in the format

```
 sdxn
```

where `x` is a letter and `n` is a number. Remember the Linux 'name' of your device if you wish to mount it.

If your program requires you to mount your device (disk etc) you can use

```
sudo mount /dev/sdxn /mnt
```

Where `sdxn` is the name of your device.

As for your problem listing contents of a directory (`ls -l | more`). I don't have much experience (none) with `more`, instead I use `less`. You can use <kbd>Enter</kbd> to move through the output at your own pace.

Comment: Unless there's an `fstab` entry for the device, `sudo mount /dev/sdxn` won't work because `mount` won't know where you want to mount it. (You have to specify the mount point too.)

Comment: Thanks I had been using a couple of other linux distros and these had mounted my disks for me during the boot. What I found by stumbling around was /dev/disk/by-label. This showed the disk label, like what you see in windows, to the /dev/sdxn. as long as the disks are different size, mfg, etc fdisk -l works fine. the tip on less is helpful. More worked on some distros but less is more better.

Comment: @brucewol If my answer solved your problem could you mark it as solved (a gray tick next to the answer. Thanks! :)